# Acumatica: AutoCallback with multiple target

Tags: c#, erp, acumatica

I have 3 grids, one grid as the head and the other as a detail, I would like to refresh 2 grid when the grid first selecting record. I've tried using `AutoCallBack`, but still can only refresh 1 grid, How to call it automatically?

Comment: Do you mean that you want grid2 to show records related to selected line in grid1? So when user selects some record in grid1, grid2 should reload records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this but a good example is to look at the "Assignment and Approval Maps" under Org -> Org Structure.

In this screen, when you click on the "Rules" grid, the "Conditions" grid auto refreshes.

This is controlled primarily by two items

1) AutoCallback commands in the top/main grid
2) Paramaters in the lower/detail grid.

For example, in the screen referenced there are two grids "topGrid" and "bottomGrid"

topGrid has the following

```
 <AutoCallBack Target="tree" Command="Refresh" ActiveBehavior="True">
   <Behavior RepaintControlsIDs="formRuleType,bottomGrid" ></Behavior>
 </AutoCallBack>
```

That will issue a refresh to the bottomGrid as the topgrid row is selected/changed.  The "KeepPosition" and "SyncPosition" flags in the definition of topGrid will force a post as rows are selected (keeping 'Current' as the current selected row.

now in the bottom grid you have the following:

```
<Parameters>
   <px:PXControlParam ControlID="topGrid" Name="routeID" PropertyName="DataValues[&quot;AssignmentRouteID&quot;]" Type="Int32" ></px:PXControlParam>
</Parameters>
```

That says that "bottomGrid" has a parm named "routeID" that pulls it's value from the "AssignmentRouteID" of the topgrid.

If you look at the BQL for the bottomGrid (primary datamember is "Rules" you'll see the following definition:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable rules([PXDBInt] int? routeID)
{
```

The definition uses the defined param, passing it into here to use for the select statement to return the correct records

Using this approach will allow you to refresh your detail grid as the head grid selects a row.  At the same time, the detail grid uses a value in the headgrid as a param for it's select statement.